# MsgWaitForMultipleObjects function not entering WAIT_TIMEOUT case

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port

We are using visual c++  to write an application which uses comm port to communicate to a device and also get a response back from it.

We are using a function MsgWaitForMultipleObjects to wait. The function looks like the following.

```
unsigned long dwRes;

while( true )
{
 dwRes=MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, &m_hPPMsgResponseReceived, false, 80, QS_ALLINPUT);
    switch(dwRes)
    {
     case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        // let's return 
        LogError("WaitOnResponseEvent", EVENT_TYPE_ERROR, 2, "%s","event.");
        ResetEvent(m_hPPMsgResponseReceived);
        return;
     case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
        // process the messages
        MSG msg;
        // see if there are any messages to process
        while( PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) )
        {  
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        break;

    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        LogError("WaitOnResponseEvent", EVENT_TYPE_ERROR, 2, "%s", "after wait for timeout.");
        ResetEvent(m_hPPMsgResponseReceived);

        return;

    default:  
        LogError("WaitOnResponseEvent", EVENT_TYPE_ERROR, 2, "%s", "default case reached");
        return;
    }
}
```

The timeout value is 80 milliseconds in this case as it can be seen in the function.

The problem is that, in some systems and sometimes (not always) the function is not entering into the WAIT_TIMEOUT case even when the time exceeds 80 milliseconds. Due to this the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects is not returning.

Can somebody let us know what might be causing this?

Also, in the above code, we are using a **While loop** for **message pumping** in the Case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:

Is this a proper way of Message Pumping.  Or using an **if condition** will suffice here??

Please let us know the correct way of handling this.

Comment: Are you sure you're not pumping messages (`WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1` case) before 80 milliseconds have elapsed, on every iteration?

Comment: Yes. Its working perfectly fine in our normal cases. As i said, we are seeing the issue only few times. Is the handling using while loop is fine or If condition can be used?

Comment: I suspect the few times you see this are related to something producing more messages than usual in the queue, and the event you're waiting for is set while you're pumping messages (and therefore outside of `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`). You may want to check the state of the event after pumping.

Comment: Or is it busy waiting in the while loop with more messages and not able to come out of it?? due to this its not entering the other case?? Just a guess. is using while loop correct there or if condition??

Comment: This code can be trivially defeated by another program that's broadcasting messages at a high rate.  Use SetTimer() instead.  Or SetCommTimeouts().

Comment: @Hans, but what of the event, then? Shouldn't the code react to the event being set ASAP instead of waiting for the whole duration of the timer?

Comment: @Frédéric - what if the event doesn't get set?  A serial port device certainly doesn't have an obligation to constantly send data :)

Comment: Try `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` with `MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE` instead.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You said that check the state of the event after pumping. Can you please elaborate how can we do that? May be using a small sample code. do we need to check it in the while loop itself?